# Minimization of an equation using Python

Tags: python, convex-optimization

I have four vectors.

```
x = [0.4, -0.3, 0.9]
y1 = [0.3, 1, 0]
y2 = [1, -0.9, 0.5]
y3 =[0.6, 0.01, 0.8]
```

I need to minimize following equation:

[image: Equation]

where `0 <= a,b,g <= 1`. I have tried to use `scipy.minimize` but I could not understand how that can be used for this equation. Is there any library for optimization that I can use or is there any easier way in Python to do it?

My ultimate goal is to find values of `a,b,g` between `0-1` that give me minimum value given these four vectors as input.

Comment: `x - y1a - y2b - y3c` is a vector, so how would you minimize this vector?

Comment: Thank you for response. I have updated the question with actual equation snapshot. I believe it is convex optimization problem and can be solved. If not, please let me know so that I can skip it for good.

Comment: `alfa =  5.25692e-11` `beta= 0.159281` and `gamma=  0.799072` ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit 0: I fixed the problem by using a Bounds instance. The array `x` should be what you are looking for. Here is the answer.

```
      fun: 0.34189582276366093
 hess_inv: <3x3 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([ 6.91014296e-01,  3.49720253e-07, -2.88657986e-07])
  message: b'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL'
     nfev: 40
      nit: 8
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([0.        , 0.15928136, 0.79907217])
```

I worked on that a little bit. I get stuck with an error, but I feel like I am on the correct way to solve it. Here is the code.

```
import numpy as np   
from scipy.optimize import Bounds,minimize

def cost_function(ini):

    x = np.array([0.4, -0.3, 0.9])
    y1 = np.array([0.3, 1, 0])
    y2 = np.array([1, -0.9, 0.5])
    y3 =np.array([0.6, 0.01, 0.8])

    L = np.linalg.norm(np.transpose(x) - np.dot(ini[0],y1) - np.dot(ini[1],y2) - np.dot(ini[2],y3))
    return L

ini = np.random.rand(3)
min_b= np.zeros(3)
max_b= np.ones(3)
bnds=Bounds(min_b,max_b)

print(minimize(cost_function,x0 =ini,bounds=bnds))
```

However, I am getting the error `ValueError: length of x0 != length of bounds`, although the lengths are equal. I could not find a solution, maybe you do. Good luck! Let me know if you find a solution and if it works!